# Separate & Combine HSV in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, toon-shading

is there a way for my toon shader to combine and separate HSV for a lighting for selective shadows
[image]

sorry for not clarifying, i want light to cast shadows on objects like this:
[image]

but it looks like this in cycles:

[image]

I think it has something to do with the separate HSV nodes so i was wondering if theres an issue with it in cycles

Comment: Could you clarify the `for a lighting for selective shadows` part please?

Comment: Shader To RGB works only in EEVEE. Maybe we can help you get around the reasons you feel the need to use Cycles.

Comment: @RobinBetts Sorry, I thought it was the HSV nodes that didn't work in Cycles but it was the Shader to RGB. I only wanted to use Cycles because it looks better and I'm fine with using EEVEE. Is there another way to do this in Cycles without the Shader to RGB node?

Comment: Cycles has a *[Toon BSDF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/toon.html)* node. You can combine a few of them to create a toon/anime shader. Have a look here: https://youtu.be/CgTOih255Mg

Comment: Thank you! The Toon BSDF works as a replacement for the node setup above.